# Почему в связке Apache24+PHP5.5 (Windows), через apache может быть ошибка, а через CLI без ошибки error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO?

Tags: php, apache, curl

1. Ошибка error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
   При соединение с api.vk.com, php программу открывая через Apache, через cmd проблемы нет. Появилось в 2023.12.5.
2. Разве в PHP, Curl будет зависеть от Apache? Просто интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Используются разные ссл библиотеки? Выглядит, как будто бы выпилена поддержка ниже тлс1.0, а Выш курл пытается использовать, например, ссл 3.0. Было бы круто -v посмотреть, чтобы увидеть, что в ssl_client_hello

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос